# Angular 2 RC3 "No provider for RouterOutletMap!" error

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app that I have just upgraded to use `"2.0.0-rc.3"`.

I am using the new router from  `"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7"`,

Now when I try to load the app in the browser I see the following exception...

```
VM17108:77 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for RouterOutletMap!
```

My app.component.ts looks like...

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';   // Load all features
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { TilesService } from '../app/shared/services/tiles.service'
import { LocationService } from '../app/shared/services/location.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'tc-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
                TilesService,
                LocationService
               ]
})

export class AppComponent {  pageTitle: string = 'TileCase'; }
```

My app.routes.ts looks like this...

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { TilesComponent } from '../app/tiles/tiles.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../app/profile/profile.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: TilesComponent }
  , { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

and my main.ts looks like this...

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
])
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This used to all be fine when using RC2. I can't figure out what I need to do to make this work again. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you provide `provideRouter(...)`?

Comment: In the app.routes which I have added above.

Comment: Check the router module in systemjs config is configured like http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any details in plnkr there?

Comment: Sorry, somehow copied the wrong link. https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Thanks, I've just dropped that into my project but the problem is still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in the Plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this one out. It was actually a Webpack error. 
Webpack wasn't setup correctly and was therefore not building out the js correctly which was leading to the error.
Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: And what was the Webpack error, if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: There was a file that Webpack was missing and not watching. Once it was linked in everything worked.

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same issue. Hoping to get some insight from you comment. Eventually I found it. In my case it turned out I had two calls to `bootstrap` funciton, one with providers, the other without.