# Why Does routerLink Fail?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**GOAL:**

Use links in `navbar.component.html`:

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['/applications']" routerLinkActive="active">Applications</a>
```

**PROBLEM:**

I get the error: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for RouterOutletMap!`

---

**CONTEXT:**

**navbar.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css'],
    directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
})
export class NavbarComponent
{
    version: string;
    versionIsVisible: boolean;
    router: Router;

    constructor(router: Router) {
        this.version = '<%= VERSION %>';
        this.router  = router;
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { ApplicationComponent } from './application/application.component';

export { Config } from './config/env.config';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    directives: [NavbarComponent, ApplicationComponent]
})
export class AppComponent
{
    constructor() {
        // console.log('Environment config', Config);
    }
}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```ts
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ApplicationComponent } from './application/application.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ApplicationComponent },
    { path: 'applications', component: ApplicationComponent },
    { path: 'signin', component: ApplicationComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ApplicationComponent },
    { path: 'help', component: ApplicationComponent },
    { path: 'view/settings/:key', component: ApplicationComponent },
    // { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```ts
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        routes
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

**package.json**

```ts
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "0.6.13"
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you initialize the router and the routes?

Comment: I added app.routes.ts. Does that help?

Comment: Do you import `ModuleWithProviders` in `@NgModule()`?

Comment: Yes. I have now included app.module.ts for you to see.

Comment: Do you use webpack, then this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053520/angular-2-rc3-no-provider-for-routeroutletmap-error Otherwise I guess I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You shouldn't need `directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]` if you import the `RouterModule` (in `NgModule`)  where you use these directives.

Comment: I'm on Gulp. As a result of exploring your previous link, I am getting a different result now: `Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.`. Progress?

Comment: This means that `routerLink` isn't instantiated. Are you sure you added `RouterModule` (or `RouterModule.forRoot()`, `RouterModule.forChild()`) to `imports: []` in every module where you use `routerLink` or `router-outlet`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122434/discussion-between-donnie-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        routes
```

should be

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing // <== change
```

Comment: I changed the two instances of `routes` to `routing`, but still get the `No provider for RouterOutletMap!`. Not sure if it's related, but I do also get `app.module.ts(22,3): error TS1146: Declaration expected.`, although I don't see the error.

Comment: Why two instances. Do you have child routes (routes in other modules)?

Comment: Two, because it occurs here `import { routes, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';` and again where you specified. I also tried changing only the instance you specified, but with the same result.